# Bugsnag + Laravel: pass contextual information with Log::error?

Tags: laravel, bugsnag

When calling `(Illuminate\Support\Facades\)Log::error` I can only see the message on Bugsnag but not the contextual information. Is there a way I can set-up Laravel/Bugsnag to also pass context?

For example, when doing `Log::error("Exception occurred.", ["Further info here."]);` only the message ("Exception occurred.") is displayed on Bugsnag.

Comment: Bugsnag certainly supports adding additional data to these events. I don't know anything about Laravel, or even PHP, but whenever you're reporting handled exceptions like this, you can supply any amount of metadata: see https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/reporting-handled-errors/ for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `Log::error` the logged message and context are parsed by the [Bugsnag PSR Logger](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-psr-logger).  The uses the context in a few ways:

1. [Extracts a `title` from the context array if set](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-psr-logger/blob/master/src/BugsnagLogger.php#L68).  This `title` will then become the context in which your error is displayed on the Bugsnag dashboard.
2. [Extracts an `exception` from the context array if set](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-psr-logger/blob/master/src/BugsnagLogger.php#L74).  This `exception` will then be used to create the error report and stacktraces.
3. [Attaches the remaining context to the report as metadata](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-psr-logger/blob/master/src/BugsnagLogger.php#L110).  If the `context` array contains sub-arrays they will be displayed on separate tabs, if not the information will be displayed in a `custom` tab in the error on the Bugsnag dashboard.

In your case, I would check out the `custom` metadata tab on your error and see if your context has turned up there.

Comment: Yep, I can see the full context inside "Custom" tab. Thanks a bunch. :)